# Importing data from api to new module - .map() not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Below is the code for my biggest nightmare yet. I keep on getting the error that the apiData.map is not a function. Any body that can help please.
I also need to know why ApiGetData do not use react please.

I do get the api data but seems that I'm importing it incorrectly to ClassFilmData and I get the .map error. All help will be appreciated.

Tried to export films, ApiGetData in various way. Help received from other platforms was implemented but did not solve the problem. Searches - other swapi projects, import data react, sandbox, repo and other platforms

```
// import React from 'react';
import { ApiToGet } from "./ApiToGet";

const ApiGetData = async function() {
  try {
    const films = await Promise.all(
      ApiToGet.map(url => fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()))
    );
    console.log("film title - ", films.results);
    return films;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("oooooooops", err);
  }
};
ApiGetData();

export default ApiGetData;
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import FilmsInfo from "./FilmsInfo";

const FilmsLoop = ({ apiData }) => {
  return (
    <div className="tc f1 unknown">
      {apiData.map((answers, i) => {
        return (
          <FilmsInfo
            key={i}
            // title={ apiData.films.results[i].title }
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FilmsLoop;
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FilmsLoop from "./FilmsLoop";
import ApiGetData from "./ApiGetData";

class ClassFilmData extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="tc f1">Wim - classfilmdata</p>
        <FilmsLoop apiData={ApiGetData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClassFilmData;
```

---

```
import React from "react";

const FilmsInfo = () => {
  return (
    <div className="tc bg-light-blue dib br3 pa3 ma3 grow bw2 shadow-5">
      <p>Planet</p>
      <p>FilmsInfo.js</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FilmsInfo;
```

Comment: You should be a bit more specific. Show us what type of data `apiData` is, log what its showup up as in the FilmsLoop componentt, etc

Answer (score 0):

That is because `apiData` is really `ApiGetData` which is a promise.

If you're trying to use the array returned by resolving this promise, you'll have to do something like this:

```
class ClassFilmData extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const apiData = await ApiGetData();
    this.setState({ apiData });

  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <p className="tc f1">Wim - classfilmdata</p>
        {this.state.apiData && <FilmsLoop apiData={ this.state.apiData }/> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```